# Gnome-do wont recognize anything after crashing

Tags: gnome-do

I was trying to activate the Skype plugin for `gnome-do` and the app crashed on me. Now after restarting it, no matter what I type inside, it wont recognize anything. I have tried to re install it clean like this

```
apt-get purge gnome-do
apt-get install gnome-do
```

and it still did not solve the problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get purge` will only purge global configuration files. You might also have to remove your user-specific configuration files and data. For `gnome-do` all files should be located under the following folders:

```
~/.gconf/apps/gnome-do
~/.local/share/gnome-do
```

**Note**: You can use `locate gnome-do` to identify any residual items pertaining to `gnome-do`.

Sources:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1210901

https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/325106

Comment: I erased those 2 folders and it did not help. The problem persists. also when I do `locate gnome-do` I get a lot of entries, and most of them don't even exist...

Comment: @Dbugger Sorry to hear that. That was the only solution I could think of. I hope you will find another way to fix this. As an aside: The `locate` index is rebuilt once a day. You can update the index by executing `sudo updatedb`. This way you can make sure that only existing files will be listed.

Comment: Oh! I did not know about the `updatedb`. I went through most of the files, and delete them all, being careful not to delete any `gnome-doc` or `gnome-document`. Mostly where all icons or cached apt-get packages. After deleting them, rebooting (to be safe) and reinstalling, it has been fixed. Thanks! :)

Comment: Even though it now has turned into a different problem... http://askubuntu.com/questions/486853/gnome-do-preferences-wont-open-and-even-crash-the-system